# How Can I wrap a Column in Datatable

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatable, datatables

I am creating a DataTable and it has Column which displays hospital name and in some rows he hospital name is too big and the text is not wrapping, I wanted to wrap that column elements.
My Table HTML looks like:

```html
 <table id="example" class="table datatable table-responsive-md table-hover wrap" cell-spacing="0" data-id-field="code" data-sort-name="value1" data-sort-order="desc" data-pagination="false" data-show-pagination-switch="false">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-field="code" class="" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
                            <th data-field="code" class="" data-sortable="true"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></th>
                            <th data-field="code" class="" data-sortable="true">Type</th>
                            <th data-field="code" class="" data-sortable="true">Total</th>
                            <th data-field="code" class="" data-sortable="true">Available</th>
                            <th data-field="code" class="" data-sortable="true">Isolation</th>
                            <th data-field="code" class="" data-sortable="true">Oxygen</th>
                            <th data-field="code" class="" data-sortable="true">ICU/HDU</th>
                            <th data-field="code" class="" data-sortable="true">Contact1</th>
                            <th data-field="code" class="" data-sortable="true">Contact2</th>
                            <th data-field="code" class="" data-sortable="true">Contact3</th>

                            <th data-field="code" class="" data-sortable="true">Last Updated</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for hospital in data %}

                        <tr>
                            <td class="" style=" ">{{hospital['hospitalName']}}</td>
                            <td class=" "><a href="{{hospital[ 'Address']}} "><i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i></a> </td>
                            <td class=" ">{{hospital['hospitalType']}}</td>
                            <td class=" ">{{hospital['bedStatus'].split('/')[0]}}</td>
                            <td class=" ">{{hospital['bedStatus'].split('/')[1]}}</td>
                            <td class=" ">-</td>
                            <td class=" ">-</td>
                            <td class=" ">-</td>
                            <td class=" ">Coming Soon<br><a href="tel:1234567890 ">1234567890</a></td>
                            <td class=" ">Coming Soon<br><a href="tel:1234567890 ">1234567890</a></td>
                            <td class=" ">Coming Soon<br><a href="tel:1234567890 ">1234567890</a></td>
                            <td class=" ">{{hospital['lastUpdated']}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

And JS initialization for that

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable({
                autoWidth: false,
                columnDefs: [{
                    // "className": "dt-center",
                    "targets": "_all"
                }],
                paging: false,
                responsive: true,
                scrollX: true,
                // responsive: true,
                info: false,
                // rowReorder: {
                //     // selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
                // },
            });
        });
```

The Table now looks like
[image]

and I wanted this something like this, but the First column text must be wraped, but here text is hidden through overflow:hidden, but it must be wrap

[image]

Comment: have you tried add `word-wrap: break-word;` on that column?

Comment: @vanowm Yeah, I tried
    `word-break: break-word;
    vertical-align: top;`

Comment: and did you set `max-width`?

Comment: @vanowm yupp, but It only shorten the width but the word didn't wrap

Comment: it doesn't make sense if it's shorten the width, it would have to do something with the long text: hide it with `overflow:hiddden;` or wrap it with `word-break: break-word;`

Comment: means by shorten width when i was using `word-break: break-word;vertical-align: top;` but it just shorten the width, and if i do `overflow:hidden` then it will just the extra text after the width

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kharvncx/

Comment: @vanowm thanks for this, but this thinks works on Normal Table, but didn't work on jQuery Datatable. I am using Datatable Library for presenting my tables. 
Official Site for Datatable Library is: https://datatables.net/

Comment: Along with other suggestions, try `white-space: break-spaces;`